# NodeJS TCP server random not responding

Tags: node.js, tcp, pm2, tcpserver

I'm listening all the connections from a GPS device who is send the data to a our server. So I create a small NodeJs app to retrieve that information.

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(connection) { 
    connection.on('drain', function(){
        console.log('drain');
    });
    connection.on('data', function(data){

        var dataGps = data.toString('ascii');

        var fecha = new Date();
        console.log(String(fecha));

        var dataArray = dataGps.split(',');
    });

    connection.on('end', function() {
        //console.log('Client disconnected'.magenta);
    });

    connection.on('error', function(err) {
        //console.log("Connection error: " + err+" ... ".red);
        //console.log('Closing connection....'.red);
        //connection.destroy();
    });

    connection.on('close', function(){
        console.log('closed event fired');
    });

});

server.on('connection', function(){
    console.log('new connection');
});

server.getConnections(function(err, count){
    if (err) {
        console.log('# Error: '+err);
    }
    console.log('Count: '+count);
});

server.listen(3001, function() { 
   console.log('Server is listening on port 3001...');
});
```

To keep running this App, I'm using pm2 ([pm2 website](http://pm2.keymetrics.io)).

Everything is fine except that sometimes this app becomes inactive and don't do anything until I restart it with pm2.

This app is in Amazon EC2 (t2.medium instance) Ubuntu 16.04.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you using Heroku?

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to mention that I'm using Amazon EC2.